# How to remind forgot password in laravel4 using auth

Tags: laravel-4

i want to send forgot password to user email using laravel4 auth component. I know auth provides remind password interface , but here issue is i dont want to use remind model which they are using in their document.
[laravel password-reminders-and-reset](http://laravel.com/docs/security#password-reminders-and-reset)

I have my user table and there is a field remind-token , i want to use this field to implement this whole function .

Please help me on this , how can i use my model for this .
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your model and implement the Laravel UserInterface, this way you get to keep core functionality in your App.
If you don't know how to do it, either check how Sentry2 implements something similar or use Sentry2 which provides user customization without breaking the core.